# Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS - MD Volume Not Found after update to 4.4.0-190-generic kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel, raid, mdadm

I just upgraded the kernel from Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-189-generic to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-190-generic and now I cannot boot as my software raid (MD) volume is not found.  I did a normal upgrade via APT.

When I select 4.4.0-189-generic in the Grub menu everything works fine.

The kernel options are identical in grub for both entries (with the exception of the kernel version):

- /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-190-generic root=/dev/md1 ro console=hvc0
- /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-189-generic root=/dev/md1 ro console=hvc0

And suggestions, or should I just stick with 4.4.0-189?

Comment: From the 189 kernel, try updating all the `initramfs` by running `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` then try the 190.

Answer (score 1):

This was the correct solution:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Thanks to Terrance!